# How to open a xaml as a window while clicking on run button

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml, app.xaml, winrt-xaml-toolkit

Can anyone help me, i want to develop one window application in which it has to open an xaml files. (Similar look when we open in visual studio)

Comment: This question is very broad and is not very clear. Try to reduce the question to a single specific problem (what exactly is failing or don't you know)